# Insert incrementing index rows from one table into another range based table

Tags: sql, oracle11g, range, sql-insert

i got two tables like this: [image: Table A] [image]

how can i insert new rows into Table A from Table B matching the given range defined in Table A ?

[image: Expected Result]

Even i thought this would be pretty straight-foward i cant find anything about ths -.-
Excuse my bad english and Thank u in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, copy Table A to Table A_Ranges.  This way it won't interfere with the result data, and you will be able to reuse it in the future.
Once Table A_Ranges is ready, clear table A.
The following will match each record from B, with the appropriate range:

```
INSERT INTO A(Range_From, Range_To, payload, IDX, Detail)
SELECT A_Ranges.Range_From, A_Ranges.Range_To, A_Ranges.payload, B.IDX, B.Detail
FROM A_Ranges
INNER JOIN B ON B.IDX BETWEEN A_Ranges.Range_From and A_Ranges.Range_To
```